# iOS Device support folder xxx is not a valid path

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I'm building a Cordova app and am trying to get local debug builds working. I've run into one snag, which gives me the following error:

> iOS device support folder '\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Applications\Xcode.app\Contents\Developer\Platforms\iPhoneOS.platform\DeviceSupport' is not a valid path, please provide a path to enable deploy to local device.

The only problem, is that I can take the same path that VS2015 is complaining about and run it in the explorer without any errors. Is there something else I need to configure for local debug builds to work?

Comment: Try setting the path of IOS device support folder in format of "\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Applications\Xcode.app\Contents\Developer\Platforms\iPhoneOS.platform\DeviceSupport"(add a slash at the head). This can be done under VS->tools->options->tools for apache cordova->ios configuration->ios device support folder.

Comment: This was a misprint on my part. What you have is exactly what's in the ios device folder support folder entry.

Comment: Try copying the contents of "\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Applications\Xcode.app\Contents\Developer\Platforms\iPhoneOS.p‌​latform\DeviceSupport" to your local folder(any folder on your local machine). And set ios support folder in taco settings to your local folder path. see [similar problem](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/vscordova/release_notes_for_update_9/#comment-2667049531).(comments by Hector Meneses).

Comment: Thanks, this is what ended up working. I think our network infrastructure was preventing my windows machine from reaching out to the apple machine.

Comment: Anyone have a solution for this? Better post it here, not give external links that do not work.
I started getting this error after installing itunes on windows machine. iTunes does not recognize the plugged in device.
I am running win10 from vmware fusion 8 from a macbook pro running macos sierra 10.12. ipad vers 2,5 running ios 9.3.5

Comment: I forgot to post an update on this! My issue turned out to be related to long folder names. There's a maximum length of file path that Cordova was expecting, and my path happened to exceed that amount without a clear error detailing why. I ended up having to rename folders and flatten the file structure, but when I did - the build ran without error.