# Can't debug on remote iOS device with Cordova and VS2017

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2017

I've been trying to get the "WeatherApp" tutorial up and running using VS2017 and Cordova. It will run fine in a simulator and will also build when I'm targeting a remote device attached to the build server. However when I actually try to debug it I get the following errors:

```
Requesting launch on remote iOS device for buildNumber 38983 on server     http://X.X.X.X:3000/cordova...
http://X.X.X.X:3000/cordova/build/38983/run The remote server returned an     error: (404) Not Found.
Requesting debug on remote iOS device for buildNumber 38983 on server     http://X.X.X.X:3000/cordova...
http://X.X.X.X:3000/cordova/build/38983/debug The remote server returned     an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

The following is output from the console window where I'm running remotebuild (I'm using version 2.1.3):

```
GET /cordova/build/tasks/49127 200 0.776 ms - 710
GET /cordova/build/tasks/49127 200 0.936 ms - 710
Done with current build. Checking for next build in queue.
GET /cordova/build/tasks/49127 200 1.534 ms - 689
GET /cordova/build/tasks/49127/log 200 23.425 ms - -
GET /cordova/build/49127/download 200 784.221 ms - -
GET /cordova/build/49127/deploy 200 798.379 ms - 726
GET /cordova/build/49127/run 404 11665.133 ms - 35
GET /cordova/build/49127/debug 500 10013.731 ms - 88
GET /cordova/build/49127 200 2.319 ms - 726
```

So for some reason it thinks it's deployed but then can't find anything when it tries to run.

The WeatherApp2\bin\iOS\Debug folder is populated with the .ipa/.plist/zip files on my Windows machine. There's nothing in the cordovaApp/bin folder on the Mac. Cordova version is 8.0.0

**Edit:**

On the Mac I can run the app by typing the following from the cordovaApp directory, and this works fine:

```
cordova run --device from cordovaApp dir
```

Comment: did you ever figure out how to fix this problem?

Comment: I didn't, but I did get it to run on an iPad by connecting it to my _PC_. I had to install iTunes, copy the device support folder from the Mac (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064117/ios-device-support-folder-xxx-is-not-a-valid-path) ), mess about a bit with provisioning profiles and eventually I got it to work...

Comment: That's a good starting point. Thanks for getting back to me about this!